# I am having trouble trying to download files with R

Tags: r, download, data-mining

So I am trying to play a bit with Covid-data analysis. I am trying to reproduce things [I read here](https://78462f86-a-e2d7344e-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/rdatamining.com/www/docs/Coronavirus-data-analysis-world.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crYcNZX0g5hddqpgNZhCuWJ8g42cwggpU8NDi0jiqy-Oi_eCYrJ-cFkE22Gq5cmAT0PXuatJ7UO6n5fp64HYBs2rm7Ln739wAls5pkMOgPE2sQj-1epykUT5TIAJs10PFUt9XuiFMk8P8i6vEjIDknC1ApBO9SShWv0ZroS5flsdWblc_sJHfLUmpJf-_x-dtGFw9Zb5qpHqTXlHAtW-BJ1yIX1COs5RSdtWudW3guShX9lee4%3D&attredirects=0).
But I have trouble from the beginning :

To download the data it uses

```
## source data files
filenames <- c('time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv',
'time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv',
'time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv')
url.path <- paste0('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/',
'master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/')

## download files to local
download <- function(filename) {
url <- file.path(url.path, filename)
dest <- file.path('./data', filename)
download.file(url, dest)
}
bin <- lapply(filenames, download)

## load data into R
raw.data.confirmed <- read.csv('./data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv')
raw.data.deaths <- read.csv('./data/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv')
raw.data.recovered <- read.csv('./data/time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv')
```

Running this code gives me the following error :

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file './data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv': No such file or directory
```

Now I have explored two directions :

- I think the link might be obsolete, so I have changed a bit, but with the same error, [to go to this page](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/10-31-2020.csv) :

> ```
> ## fichiers sources
> filenames <- c("10-31-2020.csv")
> url.path <- paste0("https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19",
>                    "blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports")
>
> ## download files to local
> download <- function(filename) {
>   url <- file.path(url.path, filename)
>   dest <- file.path('./data', filename)
>   download.file(url, dest)
> }
> bin <- lapply(filenames, download)
> ```

But I get another error :

```
 Error in download.file(url, dest) : 
  cannot open destfile './data/10-31-2020.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

- Now i thought myaby it was a `dest` problem, and created a `data` folder in my wroking directory which effectively changes my error, but still gives me one :

> ```
> trying URL 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/10-31-2020.csv'
> Error in download.file(url, dest) : 
>   cannot open URL 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/10-31-2020.csv'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In download.file(url, dest) :
>  
>  Error in download.file(url, dest) : 
>   cannot open URL 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/10-31-2020.csv'
> ```

Now I am not sure why it changes the error, as I thought the `dest` in `download(url,dest)` was a local save, but not a hard one
And I am even more unsure what to check next.

I am open to any other safer/more reliable or reproductible way to download this file.
I just want a way to automate the fact to get the new file each day (from [here](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports))

Comment: looks like you're assigning the vector of file names to `filenames` yet you're calling `filename` in the `lapply` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a trailing slash in your `dest` file path:

```
dest <- file.path('./data/', filename)
```